# Container and Component of the same Class

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React and Redux,

I'm trying to use a Class as a Redux Container (so the state is managed by reducer) and also a classic Component with another instance (no link to reducer)

So basically something like this:

```
class BaseLogo extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        let link = this.props.linkLogo || this.props.link;
        return (
            <Link className="btn btn-primary" to={link}>
                {this.props.logoName}
            </Link>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        linkLogo: state.linkLogo
    };
}

let Logo = connect(mapStateToProps)(BaseLogo);
export {Logo, BaseLogo as Button};
```

So I wanna use Logo as a Container, and Button as a Component (no reducer) with a specified props.

But as the way Redux bind it, whenever I create an instance of class Logo, there will be a reducer.

Is there somehow I can isolate the `connect()()` from the class itself ?

Thank you.

Comment: You've chosen a really confusing way to name things in this module. Why not change `class Logo` to something like `class BaseLogo` so you don't have to confusingly swapping the names around at the end with `export ... as`?

Comment: As it stands, your question is unclear. This module will export two classes: Logo (a.k.a. `logo1`), which is a Redux-connected class, and `Button`, which is a plain React.Component with no connection to Redux. If you don't want the Redux-connected component, import Button instead of Logo.

Comment: Yes, I will edit the name. But the problem here is that even if I import the Button, it shares the state of Logo (because it still connect to the reducer due to `connect`)

Comment: No, it doesn't. Button is not connected to your Redux store or reducers in any way. Only Logo is connected Redux. This is [what the docs say](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options): "It does not modify the component class passed to it; instead, it *returns* a new, connected component class for you to use."

Comment: thank you, it dues to my own bad implementation, I found the error

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, it dues to a bad implementation in the code. Thank you all